# Return statement from if __name__ == "__main__"

Tags: python

First off, I understand I am not supposed to return anything from if **name** == "**main**" and its only supposed to include its call to main().

What I am trying to do is call a python file through its path from a far away file (importing file/function is not a option)

Currently I am using this to call my file

```
result = subprocess.getstatusoutput('python farAwayFile.py')
```

However, I would like to get result from this file that would look something like...

```
("success", "I am farAwayFile print statement")
```

In my farAwayFile.py

```
def main():
    print('I am farAwayFile print statement')
    return "success"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If in my farAwayFile.py I change...

```
 if __name__ == "__main__":
    return main()
```

I get the result I want but then I have a return statement outside of a function definition which would interfere with any pylint.

So my question is, how can I return the result from my farAwayFile.py?

Comment: Why not import the function as a module you want to call in other file

Comment: You don't. You're running a separate process, so you're limited by the IPC options provided by your operating system. A process exit status can only be a simple integer (usually limited to 0 .. 255).

Comment: stop running the other python file via subprocess. import and call the main yourself. Is that an option here?

Comment: Importing the file is not a option.

Comment: @JohnS alright, why?

Comment: What do you mean by "I get the result I want"? When I try the code example with return statement outside of a function definition, I get a syntax error.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more sensible to alter `main()` to log that print statement somewhere to disk, and then pick it up from your separate process with a listener that recognises that the expected text has been logged?

Comment: @ImperishableNight That is odd I do not get a syntax error (just a pylint warning) but I actually get the result I showed above. But regardless that is one of the reasons I am no using that way.

Comment: @Karl That is a good idea Karl, I had not thought of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a UNIX shell, return value are between 0 and 255, so you can't return a string in the final return statement (well you can but the returned value can't be used).
Use `subprocess.stout/stderr` to get the print statement ; `subprocess.returncode` to get the returncode.

The best way would be to import the module.

You can also write the return value of the farAwayFile in a file (using pickle) and read it back in your main program.

Answer (score 1):

> What I am trying to do is call a python file through its path from a far away file (importing file/function is not a option)

I think it's safer to assume you *don't know how*, rather than you *can't*.

You already know the path to the file because you want to run it as a subprocess, so why not add that path to PATH? ;)

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/your/path/here")
from farAwayFile import main
```

IDEs will complain that they don't know the module imported (because it doesn't show in their dependencies; you can fix it so that suggestions show properly) and if they check PEP8, you'll get complaints about imports not being on top of the file. But it will work.

That way you don't have to change anything from your module nor write anything to disk, as someone suggested in the comments.

Comment: I think I might have left out a few important details explaining why this will not work. I was able to find another solution but I appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes, you left that out but I can't even imagine the reason *why* you can't import this? Even if it should be dynamically imported (e.g. you know the location, don't know the exact file name. you discover it during the program run), there are ways to do that and they are still more elegant and better than writing to a temp file somewhere...